# Python Can this setup have memory leak?

Tags: python

I have a few simple scripts that run continuously (24/7 forever).
However, a few of these scripts are slowly eating up all my memory.  I was confused why/how.  The general format is:

```
import time
SLEEPTIME = 10 # some number so it's not always running
def main():
    # example stuff, obviously much more complex in actual
    for i in xrange(0, 10000):
        i

def run():
    while True:
        start = time.time()
        main()
        time.sleep(SLEEPTIME - (time.time() - start))
        print('Finish loop')
if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

I run it by navigating to folder:  nohup python script.py & 
(ubuntu 12.04 server, python 2.7.3)

Is it possible for things to not get garbage collected in the format I have created?  Is there a sure proof way to make sure that the server releases all the memory?  Running garbage collection is bad (and didnt work.)

Thanks!

Comment: "example stuff, obviously much more complex in actual" -- you're asking whether it's possible that "much more complex" code has a memory leak? Yes, it is possible.

Comment: First thing I would do is be certain your memory is not just being [cached](http://blog.scoutapp.com/articles/2010/10/06/determining-free-memory-on-linux).

Comment: Without actually seeing exactly what is in the processing loop, we'll never be able to help you. Having said that, typically memory leaks in python happen due to circular references, or if you are holding references to variables inside other variables at the global scope that you don't realize.

Comment: i guess what i really want to know is that even if there are circular references inside of main loop, even if i exit out of main loop, those things wont die?

Answer (score 0):

If you're running on a *nix based system, I'd recommend you run a cron job instead.

Cron jobs work by scheduling your script every x minutes, hours or days. Your script will simply run, do some work, and instead of going to sleep just exit. Your script simplified will look as follows:

```
def main():
    # example stuff, obviously much more complex in actual
    for i in xrange(0, 10000):
        pass

def run():
    main()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

The advantage of this is that your script starts from "fresh" everytime, and you don't have to worry about memory leaks.

Here's a one line specifying your cron job to start every minute:

```
*/60 * * * * *     root python /path/to/your/script.py
```